# Is Dachstein Ice Cave a good idea for 60 year olds?

Tags: austria, salzburg, caves, ice

I was planning to visit an ice-cave near Salzburg (Werfen or Dachstein) till I read about the level of fitness required. I'm travelling with my parents both over 60- and while they are fit, my mom does have some trouble with extensive stairs.

Is Dachstein ice cave worth a good visit? From what I can tell it's easier to do than Werfen- is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dachstein Ice Cave is indeed a spectacular sight and provides a unique experience. However, visiting the cave does require a certain level of physical fitness, as it involves a cable car ride and then a steep walk, along with steps to climb. The entire tour, including the cable car ride and the walk to and from the cave, can take around 2-3 hours.

If your parents are generally fit but your mother has issues with extensive stairs, you might want to take that into consideration. The path to the cave involves a steep climb and there are steps inside the cave as well. Some visitors have noted that the tour can be rushed and might not leave much time for those who prefer to move at a slower pace.

However, the Dachstein area is not just about the ice cave. It offers stunning views of the surrounding mountains and valleys, and there are other attractions such as the Dachstein Skywalk, a platform that offers panoramic views of the Alps.

Comparatively, the Eisriesenwelt cave in Werfen is the largest ice cave in the world and involves a significant amount of climbing (around 700 steps). So if you are concerned about extensive stairs, Dachstein might indeed be the easier option.

Comment: How many steps approx does Dachstein involve- and can we leave midway in case she’s having trouble? She’s actually the fittest out of all of us - unfortunately her knees give her trouble sometimes

Comment: around 500 steps, read more here - https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g641766-d1148880-Reviews-or10-Dachstein_Giant_Ice_Caves-Obertraun_Upper_Austria.html

Comment: @VPrah, have her bring sticks, likely those fashionable extending ski/mountain walking ones will be acceptable. I am not yet 60 and have been using them for more than a decade already. I am an European woman.